# Is there any way to stop ajax call when user value is null in input

Tags: html, ajax, jsf, jsf-2.2, requiredfieldvalidator

I am using keyup event for ajax call on input tag and f:validaterequired tag. On every ajax event(Keyup) f:validaterequired is validated. I dont want to validate when value is null. Is there way to do that. I definitely need to use keyup event. I know i can use blur event but requirement need keyup event. Thanks`

```
<h:inputtext id="id" value="#{bean.somevalue}">
   <f:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{bean.listenermethod}" execute="@this 
       messages" render="@all"
 <f:validaterequired/>
</h:inputtext>
```

` I know we can use delay attribute in ajax to give some time. I dont want to use delay attribute. Currently i am using custom validator in bean to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem it works for me to add

```
onkeyup="if(!$(this).val()) return false;"
```

to the `h:inputText`.

Comment: Got it. When onkeyup event is false on inputtext. Ajax wouldn't know event is happened. And validation is not called until full page submit. Simple and great suggestion.